# Fractional Surds - Simplifying and Rational Denominator

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Simplify $\frac{3}{\sqrt5 + 2} - \frac{\sqrt2}{2.\sqrt2 - 1}$, writing your answer with a rational denominator.

So i have solved questions like this in my whole life. But i'm just confused can someone PLEASE solve it for me.?

Comment: multiply it by conjugate ... so that you can square both terms.

Comment: I've done about 5 methods, including yours . BUT IT JUST WONT WORK WHERE AM I GOING WRONG? it's really annoying...

Comment: Write up your failed attempt. Then we can tell you where you are going wrong! I don't have ESP.

Comment: it's really hard writting in that format. with the website

Comment: Please adopt a more pleasant tone, and show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: can i insert an image?

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{3}{\sqrt5 + 2} - \frac{\sqrt2}{2.\sqrt2 - 1}$$
$$=\frac{3.(\sqrt5 - 2)}{(\sqrt5 + 2).(\sqrt5 - 2)} - \frac{\sqrt2.(2.\sqrt2 + 1)}{(2.\sqrt2 - 1).(2.\sqrt2 + 1)}$$
$$=\frac{3.(\sqrt5 - 2)}{\sqrt5^2 -2^2} - \frac{\sqrt2.(2.\sqrt2 + 1)}{(2.\sqrt2)^2 - 1^2}$$
$$=\frac{3.(\sqrt5 - 2)}{1} - \frac{\sqrt2.(2.\sqrt2 + 1)}{(2.\sqrt2)^2 - 1^2}$$
$$=\frac{3.(\sqrt5 - 2)}{1} - \frac{\sqrt2.(2.\sqrt2 + 1)}{7}$$
$$=\frac{21.(\sqrt5 - 2) - \sqrt2.(2.\sqrt2 + 1)}{7}$$
$$=\frac{21.\sqrt5 - 42 - 2.2 -\sqrt2}{7}$$
$$=\frac{21.\sqrt5 - 46 -\sqrt2}{7}$$

Comment: I LOVE YOU THANK YOU !! I AM AN IDIOT >_> thank you very much :)

Comment: I'm sorry if i used an unpleasant tone. But it's really irritating when you can't solve a simple problem. But thank you for resolving this problem.